# Why tab navigation failed and produce error in console

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, tabs

I created few tabs in profile view. I want to activate certain tab from another pag e using button link.

This is my button link"

```
 <a href="{{ url('view_profil')}}/{{$valueItemregistrationkeluarga->ItemRegistrationID}}#keluarga" class="btn btn-warning btn-md">Back</a>
```

These are the sourcew of javascript in javascript folder in public used:

```
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('javascript/custom.js') }}"></script>  
  <script src="{{ url('adminlte/js') }}/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('adminlte/js') }}/select2.full.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('adminlte/js') }}/main.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('adminlte/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ url('adminlte/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js') }}">
```

These are script in header:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/jquery-ui.css') }}">
 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.css') }}"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/select.dataTables.min.css') }}"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/buttons.dataTables.min.css') }}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css') }}"/>

                                    <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css') }}"/>
 <script src="{{ asset('javascript/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>  
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

 <!-- datatable -->
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
  <link href="{{ asset('adminlte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('adminlte/css') }}/select2.min.css"/>
  <link href="{{ asset('adminlte/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{ asset('adminlte/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

When the button is clicked, it goes to the desired page but the the tab is not specified. The error in console Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function
at 3:2298" 
statement highlighted is:

```
 $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
```

I have searched through and identified possible cause is because of duplicate jquery source. But when I try delete some, still fail.

My js code is as below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">// Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
  // Javascript to enable link to tab
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
</script>
```

Comment: I see three different versions of jQuery.js. Only load one and make sure it is before all plugins or dependent code

Comment: can you show which jquery versions can be filtered? I had tried before this but failed. same error still appear